# Secured web application development in java

Tags: java, security, session, https

i have asked to do a web application using java (using open source frameworks) which should be a high secured application.

I have an impression that using https will solve all the issues related to communication between browser and server. is it correct ?

if i want to store the login details in to the session object. is it really safe if i do that assuming the connection is https.

please give me some thoughts about how to develop secured`(to sustain session ID spoofing etc..)` applications using java. all the while i was just doing normal username and password login applications where the system stores user info(like username and role) into session object.

Thanks & Regards,

Venky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly read [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Table_of_Contents#J2EE_Security_for_Developers) Guide before start developing secured web application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) to secure your application which makes it easy to handle login and logout routines and access control over your application using annotations, request maps and so on based on roles assigned to user. It handles storing login information. And if you find, that something should be done differently, you can implement your own mechanism to satisfy your needs - Spring Security is highly customizable with interfaces. Possibilities are enormous and for what I know, Spring Security is pretty much standard now for securing web application based on Java.

Personally I'm using Spring Security in grails application, and I'm very satisfied by the way it works and it's possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an impression that using https will solve all the issues related to communication between browser and server. is it correct ?

**Yes**, because it won't send request in plain form, it will encrypt and send.

> if i want to store the login details in to the session object. is it really safe if i do that assuming the connection is https.

It has nothing to do with https, it will be stored on server.

and to enable `HTTPS` in your webserver you need to configure [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) with your web/app server

Comment: @Venky: what login details you want to store in session object? like username,password or hashed password?

Comment: @Joshi thanks for your reply.. yes it has nothing to do with https. bu t the session object is tied to the session ID cookie right ?

Comment: @suresh like username and role at this moment.

Comment: yes . it is. but why there is need to cache password in session ?

Comment: @Joshi it is not storing the password. i have edited my question .. please check it again.